# PHP PayPal IPN Invalid URL Error But URL Exists and File Working

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I'm completely stumped as to why my PayPal IPN listeners wont work for my web payments standard buttons

I'm using Micah Carricks PayPal class,which is used widely and i've configured and appear to be working fine on my server

My problem arises when i attempt to process my IPN

The Sandbox simulator tool tells me my URL is invalid despite the fact the URL exists and when i access it directly handles and logs my errors fine

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Here is my listener code

```
<?php 
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', '../car_errors.log');

// instantiate the IpnListener class
include('ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();
$listener->use_sandbox = true;
$account_owner = 'MY_EMAIL';

try 
{
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit(0);
}

/*
The processIpn() method returned true if the IPN was "VERIFIED" and false if it
was "INVALID".
*/
if ($verified) 
{
    if()//My checks on the post data to update my database
    {
    } 
mail($account_owner, 'Verified Car IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
} 
else 
{
    mail($account_owner, 'Invalid Car IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
}
?>
```

I've also tried a live transaction with use_sandbox set to false and the IPN history shows the IPN as Retrying,indicating it can't contact the URL

I'm beginning to lose all hope on getting this working. I'm concerned it may possibly be my file permissions on my server,however they are all set to 664. The reason i say this is that the listeners where working on a shared host but since upgrading to a VPS has been continually problematic

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Barry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was working before you changed servers then it sounds like some kind of server configuration issue.  Since you can access the URL and you have the same URL in your Paypal config, then verify that your SSL is installed correctly.  Maybe Paypal can't see the URL due to some cert error.